# Выбор CMS при переносе

Tags: drupal, wordpress, joomla, cms, dle

Приветствую.

**Для чего мне CMS:**

Имеется лет 5, как уже рукописный движок с 3+К страниц, решил перебраться на cms. Движок выполнен в виде блога, на главной странице дайджест новостей, с превью (картинка) новости, отображение голосов за новость, количества просмотров, кратким содержимым, аватаром и ником автора, разместившего новость. При просмотре новости подробнее отображается превью, голосование за новость, ссылка на скачивание, рейтинг вложения на популярном ресурсе (обновляется динамически).

**Поддерживаемые функции CMS:**

Интересует возможность отображения структуры новостей по категориям, задание пользовательских (мета) полей в бд для движка (например, для рейтинга с популярного сайта). При переносе желательно превью легко забиндить к новости как мини для главной страницы, так и при просмотре новости отдельно большое превью. Скриншоты в новости. Ссылка на скачивание. Рейтинг, голосование. Комментарии. Подгонка шаблона под мобильные устройства. На главной странице теги под новостью. Возможность вставки обзора на видео с youtube.

**Мои мысли:**

Мои знание wordpress достаточно высоки, поэтому сразу посмотрел в сторону этой cms. Даже более менее нашел подходящий шаблон с фреймворком (Iconic One Pro), тем более хорошо СЕО оптимизирован и поддерживает сниппеты гугла. На главной странице автор с аватаром, теги, превью новости. В общем, есть что переделывать, но у wordpress meta-поля (пользовательские) - это одна таблица с id | id-новости | параметр | значение. Хотелось бы, конечно, как-то не разбивать таблицу, а иметь, например, id | название | голоса | рейтинг ...

БД буду конвертировать под cms и наполнять своим софтом, поэтому с этим трудностей не возникнет. Главное гибкость, производительность, оптимизация. Главное, чтобы cms была популярной и развивалась, как сама, так и на уровне плагинов.

Comment: >например id | название | голоса | рейтинг

Так ведь не гибко получится, а суть custom fields в гибкости. Если сильно хочется, можно вкорячить свою таблицу, например, и свои функции, чтобы дёргать из неё данные, но стоит-ли?

Вообще лучший инструмент - это инструмент хорошо знакомый. Знаком с WP, используй его, знаком с друпалом, используй его. Жумлу только не используй, она, по моим наблюдениям, какая-то совсем неправильная. Хотя, может, я её просто плохо знаю.

Comment: >в одну таблицу добавить свои поля
Кажется адекватно этого не сделать. Если сильно хочется можно сериализовать все данные и засунуть их в один custon field, но не уверен даже что это сократит колличество обращений к БД (возможно WP сразу вытягивает все кастомфилды для записи одним запросом). Во всяком случае в WP есть внешний кеш объектов (не из коробки, но прикручивается элементарно), думаю он минимизирует влияние лишних запросов.

Про друпал ничего сказать не могу. WP вполне адекватный продукт, если в нём разобраться (всё самое интересное — не на поверхности), почему-бы не использовать его.

Comment: Как писал выше, смотрю в его сторону. Но хочется рассмотреть еще варианты.

Comment: Набор пар ключ-значение это не каша, это весьма адекватная реализация кастомных филдов. Просто кастомные филды концепция универсальная, а значит уступающая более специализированным решениям (плата за гибкость).

Comment: Согласен. В wp я представляю, как все это реализовать, интересует мнение специалистов, работающие с другими cms. С wp меня смущает 3+к новостей.

Comment: Специалисты, работающие с другими CMS, скажут, что нужно использовать другие CMS. Очевидно-же (:

Не вижу, какие проблемы могут создать 3000 записей. Собственно при минимальной адекватности кода любое количество записей это проблема только базы данных.

Comment: Сейчас разрабатываю сайт на WP в базе > 25000 постов, работает нормально. 
Сайт http://lifehacker.ru/ использует CMS WordPress.

Добавить/создать свою таблицу в БД, или добавить поля в существующие таблицы не проблема.

Был опыт работы с ModX, Joomla сейчас работаю с WordPress не жалуюсь.

P.S. если хотите услышать мнение других специалистов поставьте в вопросе метки Joomla Drupal и т.д.

Comment: Добавил :) Не слышал про добавление полей к существующей таблице и в кодексе wp, не нашел информации, но предполагаю, при добавлении все равно +1 запрос, а нагрузка больше все-таки зависит от количества запросов к бд, да и к серверу в целом. Не будем углубляться, выбираем cms-ку :)

Comment: @ispro, это функционал MySQL, смотрите оператор ALTER TABLE.

Comment: Это я знаю. Дайте мне намек, как загрузить ядро wp и "подцепить" добавленное поле в одном запросе?

Comment: @ispro, get_posts|get_post возвращают объект со всеми полями таблицы, т.е. и ваши поля вернутся в объекте.  
Custom Fields можно перегружать фильтром apply_filters( "get_{$meta_type}_metadata", null, $object_id, $meta_key, $single );,  есть id поста, есть тип поста - можете вытаскивать любые данные из любых таблиц.

Категории и метки, думаю, тоже не вызовут проблем.